# Showing form input data in a different component after submitting the form in Angular

Tags: html, css, node.js, angular, typescript

I have build an employee center app that includes a form view and a details view. After filling up the form and clicking submit, the input data should be shown in the details view. I have used a EmployeeService to transfer data from form to details component. The problem is that the data is not getting transferred to the details component from form component. Can anyone suggest me some help? Here is my code-

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bnqqyc

P. S- PLEASE DO NOT FORK THE CODE IN STACKBLITZ

Answer (score 0):

You need to use BehavioSubject instead of Subject so the last emitted value will be available for new subscriber (when your employee details component is instantiated).

Also navigation should be performed after form submission handling not in the same button so it can be moved to the onSubmit() function.

Take a look at the improved stackblitz and let me know your feedback :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mmqqjk

Comment: Thank you so much sir.. It works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Accept the answer in this case

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a BehaviorSubject instead of a Subject in the service.

A Subject emits immediately when next() is invoked. In your case, the form component invokes next on the Subject, then you navigate to the detail component, and then the detail component subscribes to the Subject....but it's too late - the Subject already emitted, and you missed it.

A Behavior subject holds it's last value, and will emit that value when you subscribe to it.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a class and save your data in a variable like mentioned below and call `.next()` on the same.

```js
private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
currentObject = this.messageSource.asObservable();
```